# No sound on Fedora 27

Tags: linux, audio

I’ve recently switched to Fedora from CentOS. Everything is fine, except sound is not working.

```
[mc@dhcppc2 ~]$ speaker-test
```

returns

```
speaker-test 1.1.5
Playback device is default
Stream parameters are 48000Hz, S16_LE, 1 channels
Using 16 octaves of pink noise
Rate set to 48000Hz (requested 48000Hz)
Buffer size range from 192 to 2097152
Period size range from 64 to 699051
Using max buffer size 2097152
Periods = 4
was set period_size = 524288
was set buffer_size = 2097152
0 - Front Left
Time per period = 10.948861
0 - Front Left
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 speaker-test
```

another command aplay -l returns

```
[mc@dhcppc2 ~]$ aplay -l
 **** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
 card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: STAC9221 A2 Analog [STAC9221 A2 Analog]
 Subdevices: 1/1
 Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
 card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 1: STAC9221 A2 Digital [STAC9221 A2 Digital]   
 Subdevices: 0/1
 Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

ps -C pulseaudio gives following output

```
[mc@dhcppc2 ~]$ ps -C pulseaudio
 PID TTY          TIME CMD
 1061 ?        00:00:00 pulseaudio
 1436 ?        00:00:00 pulseaudio
```

About hardware following commands return this.

```
lscpu
[mc@dhcppc2 ~]$ lscpu
Architecture:        i686
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              2
On-line CPU(s) list: 0,1
Thread(s) per core:  1
Core(s) per socket:  2
Socket(s):           1
Vendor ID:           GenuineIntel
CPU family:          6
Model:               15
Model name:          Intel(R) Pentium(R) Dual  CPU  E2180  @ 2.00GHz
Stepping:            13
CPU MHz:             1390.073
CPU max MHz:         2000.0000
CPU min MHz:         1200.0000
BogoMIPS:            4000.04
L1d cache:           32K
L1i cache:           32K
L2 cache:            1024K
Flags:               fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge        mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts cpuid aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm lahf_lm dtherm
```

And this

```
[mc@dhcppc2 ~]$ (lspci -nn | grep -i audio)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family High             Definition Audio Controller [8086:27d8] (rev 01)
```

And one more

```
[mc@dhcppc2 ~]$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 1a2c:2124 China Resource Semico Co., Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked the poster in Chat what his profile setting in the configuration tab of `pavucontrol` was. He said it was "Digital stereo (IEC958) output + analog stereo input".

I suggested changing that to "Analog Stereo Duplex", which apparently fixed the problem.

I'm not sure why one worked and not the other, but it seems that bad default settings in sound are frequently a source of problems. And "Analog Stereo Duplex" is a conservative choice which often seems to work.

The other common problem with default settings in sound cards is that some channels are muted or just too low. This is usually fixed by going into `alsamixer` and unmuting or bringing the level up.