# "package X requires Y, but none of the providers can be installed"

Tags: fedora, upgrade, dnf

While upgrading to fedora 28, I ran two commnads

```
sudo dnf upgrade --refresh
sudo dnf install dnf-plugin-system-upgrade
```

These worked but next command
    sudo dnf system-upgrade download --releasever=28
got into this

```
Error: 
Problem: package alsa-plugins-freeworld-lavcrate-1.1.5-1.fc27.i686 requires libavcodec.so.57, but none of the providers can be installed
- ffmpeg-libs-3.3.7-1.fc27.i686 does not belong to a distupgrade repository
- problem with installed package alsa-plugins-freeworld-lavcrate-  1.1.5-1.fc27.i686
```

My machine has problem with sound:
[No sound on Fedora 27](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/441069/no-sound-on-fedora-27)
Tell me what to do?

Comment: Try to remove the `alsa-plugins-freeworld-lavcrate` package with `dnf remove alsa-plugins-freeworld-lavcrate` and then try the update again with `sudo dnf system-upgrade download --releasever=28`.

Comment: This worked for me. But to remove packages I wrote dnf remove alsa-plugins-freeworld-lavcrate-1.1.5-1.fc27.i686 dnf remove ffmpeg-libs-3.3.7-1.fc27.i686

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> If some of your packages have unsatisfied dependencies, the upgrade will refuse to continue until you run it again with an extra `--allowerasing` option. **This often happens with packages installed from third-party repositories for which an updated repositories hasn't been yet published.** Please study the output very carefully and examine which packages are going to be removed. None of them should be essential for system functionality, but some of them might be important for your productivity.
>
> - In case of unsatisfied dependencies, you can sometimes see more details if you add --best option to the command line.
> - If you want to remove/install some packages manually before running `dnf system-upgrade download` again, it's advisable to perform those operations with `--setopt=keepcache=1` dnf command line option. Otherwise the whole package cache will be removed after your operation, and you'll need to download all the packages once again.

https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/DNF_system_upgrade

Comment: Yep, but removal of these softwares is the only choices. I appreciate your answer @sourcejedi

Comment: @PrabhjotSingh sure. I don't know what lavcrate is or why you have it installed. So I don't have advise on whether you should update without it, or wait before upgrading to F28. Only that it is not necessarily *required* to upgrade to F28 straight away. F27 is still supported with security updates until F29 is released.

Comment: I updated without it but then too, my machine gets struck on starting Fedora 28. I f posted a separate question about it. When i removed ALSA and ffmpeg this worked.  I m

Comment: One thing beyond my comprehension is that my machine is 32 bit but lscpu      Architecture: i686 CPU op-mode(s): 32-bit, 64-bit

Comment: off-topic for this Q. but I bet your machine is 64-bit.